# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when accessing content behind GCP load balancer on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've created a public storage bucket and uploaded a static website into it. I have assigned a load balancer to this bucket, and **everything works when I'm using this load balancer's IP address** to connect to the website. **I'm using HTTP**, no SSL certificates for now.

However, **it all breaks when I'm accessing the page using domain name on Chrome** (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6uL9.png)). I registered a type A record that points to a proper IP address, and it works on Edge or Firefox. Heck, it even works on my mobile Chrome browser or on some of my coworkers' desktop Chrome apps (but not on every one of them). It is also not working when using Opera (again - not on every PC, but on most of them), so basically I think it has to be a problem with Chrome-based browsers.

Also, I've got a load balancer assigned to a Kubernetes Ingress, and when I'm accessing the pods data through Chrome, I'm getting the same error. All seems to work fine through Postman/curl etc.

I've tried many solutions found on Google (changing some flags in my Chrome, flushing my DNS, etc.) - none of them worked. Please help, I'm by no means a networking expert, and I'm really frustrated by the lack of any clear documentation about this kind of error...

Comment: Hi Filip, we observe similar issues with assets and gcp lb, were you able to resolve your issues?